# How do I run multiple terminals in vps

Tags: 16.04, command-line, server, ssh

I have 2 flask restful API's .
On my localhost, I open up a terminal and run `uwsgi --ini /path-to-ini-file1`. For 2nd API, I open up yet agan a new terminal and run `uwsgi --ini /path-to-ini-file2`.
In VPS, I have only a single ssh window.
How do I run those 2 on terminals in vps using ssh. Should I create a bin/bash script to achieve that?
Any suggestion would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can't you just make a second ssh connection from an other terminal-window ?

Comment: @SorenA: Thanks for replying, Sir. So is it like I open up as many ssh windows I want, run commands, and then close them up, and my server would keep running them, until I restart it? Upon closing the ssh on my home pc, would the command be still running on the server? Fairly new to vps, so pardon me for silly questions.

Comment: If you run the command in foreground (thats what you normally do, the command will terminate when you closethe ssh connection - but that's also what happens when you close the terminal running locally. Maybe you should look at the `screen` tool. That allows you to have many sessions running at once, and they will survive disconnection / connection to your remote server / VPS. You might have to install screen on your VPS.

Comment: @SorenA: Thanks a lot, Sir. Your comment cleared all my doubts, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run commands in background and do not have them attach to the terminal you need to use something like:

```
nohup uwsgi --ini /path-to-ini-file1 >out1.log 2>err1.log&
nohup uwsgi --ini /path-to-ini-file2 >out2.log 2>err2.log&
```

And you can run as many as need servers (limited by RAM and processor power).

And after you logour from the server you will have them run

Comment: .Thanks a lot for your answer, Sir. Trying right now, what you have just suggested

Answer (score 0):

If this is supposed to run on an unattended machine, make these a service, so that they are automatically taken care off (started,restarted, logged...). It is not difficult to make a [systemd service](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/systemd-essentials-working-with-services-units-and-the-journal).

Comment: Thanks a lot for telling something new to me , Sir. Visited the link you posted, very knowledgeable.